# CodeIgniter + CSS

Tags: css, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

Good Day, I'm learning CodeIgniter with Smarty. My CSS file is stored in

```
/App01/application/views/css/main.css
```

To link my CSS I use:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:88/APP1/application/views/css/layout.css" media="screen" />
```

But CSS is not applied on my page. When I open CSS URL, I get a message:

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /APP1/application/views/css/layout.css on this server.
```

Please, what am I doing wrong? I'd like to keep my CSS together with the view because in future I'd like to learn how to create multiple themes and I thing the CSS should be kept within the theme folder.

Can I replace URL path to CSS file with some Smarty variable so that when I move my application I do not need to change CSS URL path in templates manually?

Thank you in advance! Vojtech

Comment: +1 for starting a thread with Good Day.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Anything in the `/application` folder of CodeIgniter should be considered out-of-bounds. For the best security, you should actually consider keeping `/application` above your `www` or `public_html` folder in a structure such as this:

```
– application
    – controllers
    – models
    – views
    – ...
– system
    – core
    – libraries
    – ...
– public_html
    – index.php
```

This makes your application code safer.

I’d advise creating your client-side scripts and CSS in a public folder. For example `public_html/css` and `public_html/js`. Or, if you wanted to go down the theme route, possibly name each CSS file as the name of the theme, so you’d have `css/theme1.css` and `css/theme2.css`.

If your site will always work from the root of a domain, then you can just use:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/layout.css" media="screen" />
```

But if you feel that you’re going to be moving all sorts of things around, then consider preparing the file location in your controller before sending it to Smarty.

```
$this->load->helper('url');
$this->smarty->assign('css_file', base_url("css/theme1.css"));
```

That will return:

```
http://localhost/app1/css/theme.css
```

Or whatever your CodeIgniter URL is.

Comment: Many thank for your advice Thomas, it helped me a lot to understand!

Answer (score 1):

This will help to link css to codeigniter.

The `link_tag` is used to link resources and you can use `helper` function.
For example html helper, url helper, email helper, etc.

In your controller you have to create a function something like

```
<?php 
class Home extends CI_Controller{
    public function helper(){
        $this->load->helper('html');    
        $this->load->view('index');
    }
}
?>
```

And your `index.php` in `view` folder use link_tag keyword.

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<?php echo link_tag('App01/application/views/css/main.css');?>
</head>
<body>
    <?php 
     .......
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a symlink to your servers document root folder. (www/public_html/htdocs)

```
cd (document root folder)
ln -s (/App01/application/views/css) .
```

This way you can access your css folder and keep the current structure.