# css,javascript path recognize in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am very new in Codeigniter...i have some basic ideas..but not sufficient.lets talk about the problem....

I have a static website..which will be dynamic soon.Now this static website contains css,css3 in a css forlder, javascript in javascript folder,image in images folder.Now i am wanting to set this static website into codeigniter.I copy paste the whole codes including index.php and other pages and the folders(css,javascript.images)into the `view` folder of codeigniter.for all of your kind information my index.php page is just like that...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Home</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/reset.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/slider.css">
<!--<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Great+Vibes' 
rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>-->
<script src="<?= base_url() ?>path/images/js/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?= base_url() ?>path/images/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="<?= base_url() ?>path/images/js/tms-0.4.1.js"></script>
<script src="<?= base_url() ?>path/images/js/vpb_script.js"></script>
<script src="<?= base_url() ?>path/images/js/pop.js"></script>

<!--start popup window ref-->
<link href="css/colorbox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script src="<?= base_url() ?>path/js/jquery_002.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $(".image_show").colorbox({rel:'image_show', transition:"fade"});

    });
</script>
<!--end popup window ref-->

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){                   
        $('.slider')._TMS({
            show:0,
            pauseOnHover:true,
            prevBu:false,
            nextBu:false,
            playBu:false,
            duration:700,
            preset:'fade',
            pagination:true,
            pagNums:false,
            slideshow:8000,
            numStatus:false,
            banners:false,
            waitBannerAnimation:false,
            progressBar:false
        })      
    });
</script>
<style type='text/css'>
/*This will work for chrome */
    #vpb_general_button{
        padding:5px 2px 4px 2px;
    }

/*This will work for firefox*/
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    #vpb_general_button{
        padding:5px 2px 6px 2px;
    }
}
</style>
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
   <div style=' clear: both; text-align:center; position: relative;'>
     <a href="http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/
internet-explorer/products/ie/home?ocid=ie6_countdown_bannercode">
       <img  src="http://storage.ie6countdown.com/assets/100/
images/banners/warning_bar_0000_us.jpg" border="0" 
height="42" width="820" alt="You are     using an outdated browser. For a faster, 
safer browsing experience, upgrade for free today." />
    </a>
  </div>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/html5.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/ie.css">
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<!--<div class="bg-top">-->
<div class="bgr">
<!--==============================Wrapper=================================-->
<div class="wrapper">
<?php 
   include_once('header.php');
   include_once('navigation.php');
   include_once('slider.php');
   include_once('offers.php');
   include_once('invite.php');
   include_once('testimonial.php');
   include_once('special_item.php');
   include_once('footer.php');
   include_once('popup.php');
   ?>
```

and my conroller is like that...

```
<?php
class Site extends CI_Controller
{
  function home()
 {
    $this->load->view('index');
 }


}
```

?>

the problem is that my webpage is loading but without the design,may b its not finding the javascript or css

i know i am making a mistake here..bur i can't fix it out,please help me to fix it out..

Comment: You need to edit the `.htaccess`. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060733/codeigniter-loading-css)

Answer (score 3):

usually we put all files like that into an "assets" folder in the application root, and then make sure to use an Asset_Helper to point to those files. This is what CodeIgniter suggests

Answer (score 1):

The folders (css, javascript, images) should NOT be pasted into the `views` folder, but in the folder where your Code Igniter's `index.php` is. (Usually, the parent folder of the `application` folder, i.e., your site public root.)

Answer (score 1):

You can add `<?= base_url() ?>` to all your css link.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" 
href="<?= base_url() ?>path/to/css/reset.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a more comprehensive answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8848297/codeigniter-css). You may want to consider permissions issues that could be going on as a result of placing your css dir within the application/views dir.
Create an assets dir outside the application dir and use the URL helper by loading it into your controller like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7503302/how-to-get-base-url-in-codeigniter-2).